# How to use a stream builder to return message from the last message field in my message collection

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Please i need stream builder widget to return this last message(red rectangle box) in my message collection. The one i used below return a null String must be provided in the Text widget.

````
        class MessageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
          final String uid;
          MessageScreen(this.uid);
          @override
          _MessageScreenState createState() => _MessageScreenState();
        }
        
        class _MessageScreenState extends State<MessageScreen> {
          String uid;
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                elevation: 0.0,
                title: Center(
                  widthFactor: 5,
                  child: Text(
                    'Message',
                    style: mystyle(
                      20.0,
                      Style.Colors.titleColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              body: LastMessageContainer(
                  stream:
                      messageCollection.orderBy('lastMessage.timestamp', descending: true).where('users', arrayContains: uid).snapshots()),
            );
          }
        }
        
        class LastMessageContainer extends StatelessWidget {
          final stream;
        
          LastMessageContainer({
            @required this.stream,
          });
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return StreamBuilder(
              stream: stream,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  var docList = snapshot.data.docs;
        
                  if (docList.isNotEmpty) {
                    Message message = Message.fromMap(docList.last.data());
                    return SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                      child: Text(
                        message.message,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return Text(
                    "No Message",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 14,
                    ),
                  );
                }
                return Text(
                  "..",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
         }
         ```
````

[image: message collection screenshot]]

The error which it returned i.e a null String must be provided in the Text widget occurred at the Text(message.message) when i tried to get the message from the last message field under the message collection.

Comment: This looks more like javascript rather than java. Please choose a single language. Java has no relationship to javascript.

Comment: I dont understand your comment. i need a widget to get the data from the last message field in my message collection @NomadMaker

Comment: Is the language you are using to write this javascript?

Comment: Java @NomadMaker

Comment: I have a lot of experience with java, and this doesn't look like java I know.

Comment: Alright, so what do you suggest i can do to get the last message from the last message field and  display each users last message conversation @NomadMaker

Comment: I am not novice to java,  so I know what I am doing. This is java language.

Comment: Java doesn't have code like ``elevation: 0.0``. This isn't java code.

Comment: that's dart sdk on flutter.@NomadMaker

Answer (score 0):

First of all You have to store timestamp at with message was generated. After that you can simply call "orderBy" on your collection and order it by timestamp.

Comment: Please could you check the screenshot i posted, because i already stored the message in timestamp but to now get the data from the last message field in now the issue.my aim is to save each user last message conversation.thanks

Comment: try to just write "timestamp" and not "lastmessage.timestamp"

Comment: When i edit to "timestamp", it return no message.

Comment: have you tried to put ascending instead of descending ?

Comment: Still not returning any data